# Extension Properties

Tags: c#

HI,
I Am creating one user Control in windows Application which contain Treeview With n Nodes 
The NUmbe OF Nodes Will be decided At Runtime. 
I Want To Store Some Data On Each TreeNode Which I Can Retrieve When TreeNode Get Selected. 
Problem is that some node will store custid,custname.. 
some store studid,studname,,,,,,

I Have used Extension Methods 
static class Extension 
    { 
        static Dictionary m_Dictionary=new Dictionary(); 
        public static void SetTags(this TreeNode p_TreeNode, Dictionary  p_Dictionary)
        { 
            m_Dictionary = p_Dictionary; 
        } 
        public static Dictionary GetTags(this TreeNode p_TreeNode) 
        { 
            return m_Dictionary; 
        } 
    } 
but it will not help becase iam getting data on the last node only... 
how i can achieve this .. 
is there is something like etension properties....or whether there is any other solution. 
Thank In Advance,,,,,,,

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing called etension properties exist, if you want add simple string data to tree nodes use `Tag` property.

Comment: i cant use tag because it will be confusing 
each node contain different data

Comment: are you trying to add objects for additional info?? Its really not clear what kind of data u r trying to store

Comment: yes .
i have created cutom eventarument class which will contain data property which is a dictionary object.

Comment: @Sukesh Marla: You can still determine the type held byt the Tag property of the node at runtime; this is probably the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no such thing as of C# 3.0.

Look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138367/most-wanted-feature-for-c-4-0